# Angular2 - View updates for some values but not others when subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to set up a catalog of items that can be searched through. My catalog component has a few subscriptions to observables. Whenever the search term is updated, it will apply that query to a list of items and return the matching ones. The search function is located in a separate component which does the filtering and sends a value to the searchService to indicate when it starts and stops searching. I want to tap into this value change with a separate loader subscription and update the "isLoading" boolean to display a spinner when the search function is running.

catalog.cmp.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res) =>{
        this.stock = res;
        this.allstock = res;
    });

    this.searchsubscription = this.searchService.termUpdate$.subscribe(
            (item) => {
                this.searchTerm = item;
                //the following searches through the allstock array and returns the list to be displayed with ngFor
                this.stock = this.search.transform(this.allstock,{query:this.searchTerm})
            },
            (err) => {console.log(err)}
     );

     this.loadsubscription = this.searchService.loadUpdate$.subscribe(
         (res) => {
            this.toggleLoader(res)
         },
         (err) => {console.log(err)}
     );
}
```

The toggleLoader() function looks like this:

```
toggleLoader(state){
    this.isLoading = state;
    console.log("ISLOADING",this.isLoading)
}
```

search.service.ts:

```
export class SearchService {
private isLoading;
private searchTerm = '';
private termSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
termUpdate$ = this.termSource.asObservable();
private loadSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
loadUpdate$ = this.loadSource.asObservable();

constructor(){}

setTerm(term){
    this.searchTerm = term;
    this.termSource.next(term);
    console.log(this.searchTerm, 'term updated')
}
getTerm(){
    return this.searchTerm;
}
setLoadState(state: boolean){
    this.isLoading = state;
    this.loadSource.next(state);
    console.log(this.isLoading, 'loading status')
}
getLoadState(){
    return this.isLoading;
}
```

}

In my component template, I have this setup:

```
<div>{{isLoading}}, {{searchTerm}} <-- this part is for debugging
    <spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></spinner>
    <button (click)="toggleLoader(true)">true</button>
    <button (click)="toggleLoader(false)">false</button>
</div>
<span *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <div class="row"
    *ngFor="let item of stock| paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">
    ...
    </div>
</span>
```

So every aspect of the view updates fine except for the isLoading value. But the correct value of isLoading displays in the console and at the right times (true when the search term is sent and the filter is running, and false when the new stock array is returned and ngfor updates). The change just isn't being detected in the view. My toggleLoader debugging buttons will update the view properly however.

I've tried many of the solutions posted in similar questions, such as wrapping the body of toggleLoader in zone.run() or calling change detection manually with ChangeDetectorRef. I can even try not using the loadsubscription and instead call toggleLoader before I call search.transform and again when it's done, like so:

```
this.searchsubscription = this.searchService.termUpdate$.subscribe(
        (item) => {
            this.searchTerm = item;
            this.toggleLoader(true); //the console is still updated at the correct times with this method
            this.stock = this.search.transform(this.allstock,{query:this.searchTerm})
            this.toggleLoader(false);
        },
        (err) => {console.log(err)}
 );
```

Minimal plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/lD4gZq
Note: In the full app, the searchbar is not a child component of the catalog, which is why the search term updating is going through an external service to being with.

I've been researching change detection and trying to fix this for a while now but I honestly can't figure out why this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to create a minimal plunker for this?

Comment: I don't think so because it would be hard to replicate the large amount of data I have to search through. Part of the problem may have something to do with the fact that I'm trying to change the spinner visibility while the search and ngFor are operating on a large dataset.

Comment: Maybe you can fake out search and list with something simple, and keep just the spinner part. So then it will be clear what the cause is

Comment: Okay I updated the original post with a plunker. It's not exactly like the full app but it's hopefully close enough.

Comment: I had a look at the plunk, Not sure if error is reproducible there. Can you point me at the error use case in plunk please